# How can I store multiple generic types in a List<MyClass<object>>?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a class `TokenDefinition<T>` where `T` is unconstrained

```
public class TokenDefinition<T> { ... }
```

A module outputs a stream of these tokens. The type information is useful elsewhere, but for now, I just need an easy way to collate them/pass them around.

I had expected this to work:

```
var expected = new List<TokenDefinition<object>>();
expected.Add(new TokenDefinition<string>());
expected.Add(new TokenDefinition<double>());
expected.Add(new TokenDefinition<Keyword>()); // Keyword is an enum
```

But that gives me a `Cannot convert from TokenDefinition<string> to TokenDefinition<object>`

So I tried casting before insertion to be explicit...

```
expected.Add((TokenDefinition<object>) new TokenDefinition<string>());
```

Same issue, different wording: `Cannot convert type TokenDefinition<string> to TokenDefinition<object>`

What am I missing?

*Everything* is an object, so I'm struggling to understand why this (widening) conversion isn't allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed rather confusing, you should read up on covariance and contravariance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

This will work:

```
public interface ITokenDefinition<out T>{}
public class TokenDefinition<T> : ITokenDefinition<T> {  }

void Main()
{

    var expected = new List<ITokenDefinition<object>>();
    expected.Add(new TokenDefinition<string>());
}
```

**!!! The co/contra-variance thing only works on interfaces ... !!!**

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something obvious. I've been in Python land for so long, my strong typing is a little rusty,

Comment: No problem, dont forget "out" parameters can only be used on return types. And "in" on method arguments...

Comment: Where do enums fall (if you know?) I'm getting `cannot convert Keyword [and enum] to object`.

Comment: Enums are value objects (structs too), but still you should be able to put them as generic argument.